# Image disappears if i apply RoundedBitmapDisplayer() with Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, imageview, universal-image-loader

I am using Universal Image Loader to load some images,and i would like to use the RoundedBitmapDisplayer feature. Without using it, the images load perfectly, but if I add:

```
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
        .cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))     //this makes the issue
        .build();
```

the whole image disappears and doesnt show at all. Even with the value of 1 the same happens. If I omit that line, it shows okay. I also want to ask if this is the correct way and order for using imageloader, so the pseudo-code with the issue, maybe it is more helpto answer my main question:

```
public class MyRoom{
...
DisplayImageOptions options;
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
ImageLoaderConfiguration config;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
         .build();
options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_image)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.image_for_empty_url)
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))     //this makes the issue
            .build();
...
}


class RoomItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
...
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
...
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(config);
imageLoader.displayImage(Comment_img.get(position), viewHolder.img, options);
...
}
...
}

}
```

Comment: up, i have some problems using roundedbitmapdisplayer too

Comment: I also tried to find other bitmapDisplayer, like CircleBitmapDisplayer, it also makes the image disappear

Comment: (well my issu is a little different, my images are modified) if you find a good solution i'm interrested

Comment: I updated my imageloader to 1.9.2 yesterday, before with the 1.7.0 version it was working. But also with that, if I changed the value of RoundedBitmapStlye to 20, it not only rounded the imageview, but also modified the image by zooming in.

Comment: Same for me, that's weird

Answer (score 4):

Assign the ImageView's layout_width and layout_height in specific value :

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:contentDescription="@null"/>
```